# Loss function gradient not computing - FastAI Convolutional VAE

Tags: pytorch, fast-ai

I modified the example from the [Pytorch VAE example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/vae/main.py) to be a convolutional network. I then wanted to implement this in FastAI.

```
class convVAE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, dim_z=20):

    super(convVAE, self).__init__()

    self.cv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, stride=2)
    self.cv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=2)
    self.fc31 = nn.Linear(2304, dim_z)
    self.fc32 = nn.Linear(2304, dim_z)
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(dim_z, 2304)
    self.cv5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 3, stride=2)
    self.cv6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 1, 3, stride=2, output_padding=1)

def encode(self, x):
    h1 = F.leaky_relu(self.cv1(x))
    h2 = F.leaky_relu(self.cv2(h1)).view(-1, 2304)

    return self.fc31(h2), self.fc32(h2)

def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
    std = torch.exp(0.5*logvar)
    eps = torch.randn_like(std)
    return mu + eps*std

def decode(self, z):
    h5 = F.leaky_relu(self.fc4(z)).view(-1, 64, 6, 6)
    h6 = F.leaky_relu(self.cv5(h5))
    return torch.sigmoid(self.cv6(h6))

def forward(self, x):
    mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
    z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
    return self.decode(z).view(-1, 784), mu, logvar

def get_loss(res,y):
    y_hat, mu, logvar = res

    BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(
        y.view(-1, 784),
        y_hat,
        reduction='sum')

    KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar -
                           mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())

    return BCE + KLD
block = DataBlock(
blocks=(ImageBlock(cls=PILImageBW),ImageBlock(cls=PILImageBW)),
get_items=get_image_files,
splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
get_y=(lambda x: x),
batch_tfms=aug_transforms(mult=2., do_flip=False))

path = untar_data(URLs.MNIST)
loaders = block.dataloaders(path/“training”,num_workers=0,bs=32)
loaders.train.show_batch(max_n=4, nrows=1)

mdl = convVAE(5)
learn = Learner(loaders, mdl, loss_func = convVAE.get_loss)
learn.fit(1, cbs=ShortEpochCallback())
```

The gradient is not computing from the loss, as the parameters all become NaN after one step. The loss function does compute but was relatively large O(1e6). The model and loss function work in the native Pytorch implementation.

Comment: Shouldn't init be \_\_init\_\_ in your model class definition?

Comment: you know that might have been it.. at some point it started working and I might have just fixed this without thinking as it was corrected since. Yet I am still getting poor performance on identical model in FastAI vs with the example ADAM setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your BCE calculation:

```
BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(
    y.view(-1, 784),  # this should be your model prediction
    y_hat,  # this should be the ground truth
    reduction='sum')
```

A simple fix is to swap the two arguments.

Comment: I think this was the solution, at some point I changed it and it did start working. I am still getting much worse performance from the fast-ai version on training loss and the result does not converge to a good solution :/

Comment: Several things to consider. First, the fast-ai version prints average batch loss while the pytorch version prints average instance loss. The denominators used are different. To compare them fairly, we have to use the same metric. Second, it's better to increase batch size. In the pytorch example, it uses 128 by default. Third, adding batch normalization may be helpful to stabilize and accelerate the CNN training.